# Android studio reports " Gradle sync failed: Could not determine artifacts"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, offline-mode

Gradle sync failed: Could not determine artifacts for com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1: No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions says it all, **DISABLE OFFLINE MODE**

Go to File > Settings > Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work".